# whats the standard way to setup a casperjs for travis-ci testing

Tags: casperjs, travis-ci

surprisingly enough, when thinking about js tremendous popularity in GitHub repos, there is no "offical" guide to testing frontend js with Travis-ci (only node.js, a very specific subset). from my research I found out a lot of big js projects don't have Travis-ci integration (e.g jQuery) or have a very minimal travis setup (see [backbone](https://github.com/jashkenas/backbone)) which uses the default `npm test`.

I know travis-ci runs `npm test`as default and runs the `test` named scripts from `package.json`. and I found a few examples running phantomjs for headless testing (which the docs don't give any details about setting up) but couldn't find canonical examples for how to setup casper.js integration tests with travis-ci.

I'll be help for help and guidance with this

Answer (score 3):

Seems the canonical way is hiding the tests behind the default `npm test` which usually triggers a script (or a grunt task) running the test suite.

you can look at the `.travis.yml` in a [small project I coded](https://github.com/alonisser/opentaba-client/blob/master/.travis.yml) to see how to install casperjs for the testing.